# Installing/Running an app generated from Electron-package

Tags: electron

I have generated an app using electron-package. when running the exe generated in client's windows PC its not running. Is there any prerequisites to be installed in client PC? I haven't installed Node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running your .exe from the command line. Maybe you'll be able to figure out what's causing your app to crash. I had the same problem, double-clicking the .exe would do nothing. When I ran the .exe from the command line (i.e. `out\myApp-win32-x64\myApp.exe`), I was able to see my app's `console.log()` and `console.err()`, and I realized what my problem was.

In my case, my app was using paths relative to `process.cwd()`, which were messed up when running the app directly from the .exe. That caused the app to crash even before showing the window, hence why nothing seemed to be running.